# PHP MYSQL Displaying the same data from table to another page

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="card-header py-3">
          <h4 class="m-2 font-weight-bold text-primary">Asset Approval List</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0"> 
           <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Asset</th>
                 <th>Serial Number</th>
                 <th>Model Name</th>
                 <th>Owner ID</th>
                 <th>Owner Name</th>
                 <th>Description</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
      <tbody>
    
    <script>
    function approval(){
      window.location.href = "AddAssetApproval.php";
    }
    </script>

<?php    
            
$query = "SELECT * FROM waiting_approval";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Category'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['SerialNumber'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['ModelName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['OwnerID'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['OwnerName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="button" value = "View" onclick="approval()"></td>';
    echo '</tr> ';
}
?> 

<div class="title">
  Add Asset Approval Form
</div>

<div class="form">
   <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Category</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="Category">
   </div>  
     
   <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Serial Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="SN">
   </div>  

  <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Model Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="Model Name">
   </div> 

   <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Owner ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="OID">
   </div> 

   <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Owner Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="OName">
   </div> 

  <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Description</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" name="Desc">
   </div>
```

Asset Approval List is a table with lots of row of data and a button, after clicking the button, it will link to Asset Approval Form. I would like to fetch the data from the same row in Asset Approval List to my Asset Approval Form. The data in the table of Asset Approval List is fetched from mysql phpmyadmin. Any idea how to link the same data to Asset Approval Form?

This is my Asset Approval List
[image: This is my Asset Approval List]

This is my Asset Approval Form

[image: This is my Asset Approval Form]

Comment: Is there a unique ID column in the table?

Comment: yeap Serial Number is my unique ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's a unique ID column in the table, you should include that in the call to `approval()`:

```
    echo '<td><input type="button" value = "View" onclick="approval(\'' . $row['SerialNumber'] . '\')"></td>';
```

Then change `approval()` to include the ID in the URL.

```
    function approval(serial){
      window.location.href = "AddAssetApproval.php?serial=" + serial;
    }
```

And `AddAssetApproval.php` should use `$_GET['serial']` to display the appropriate approval form for that serial number.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM waiting_approval WHERE SerialNumber = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['serial']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: may i know where to put $_GET['serial'] at?

Comment: Use it when you're looking up the record to approve.

Comment: I've added all of those but when i clicked on the button I get this error -> Uncaught ReferenceError: LPA101121104552 is not defined
onclick @ C:\xampp\htdocs\hallbar23\hallbar\AssetApprovalList.php:105:191

Comment: I mistakenly used PHP `.` instead of JS `+` for concatenation in the `approval()` function.

Comment: owhhhhh so what should i do to achieve the solution?

Comment: i still get the same error even though i change . to +

Comment: What is `LPA101121104552`?

Comment: Oh, that must be a serial number. I assumed they were numbers, so I didn't put it in quotes in the `onclick`. I've added the quotes now.

Comment: the serial number thingy is solved but then now they said $serial is not defined

Comment: Come on, it should be obvious that that was just a typo for `serial`.

Comment: heyyyy i encounter another problem while using the solution, it says mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hallbar23\hallbar\AddAssetApproval.php on line 86

Comment: Fixed it. Needed to call `$stmt->get_result()`.